# TeamViewer meetings on a LAN connection

Tags: lan, remote-access, teamviewer, meetings

I know that we can use TeamViewer on a LAN connection without internet for remote control. I was wondering whether we can use meetings to connect via LANs without internet as well. I tried doing this but I couldn't find the feature.

Comment: Too bad noone ever answered this question!  I'd love to know how to do that, too.

Answer (score 2):

That solves the question. I think it works only with TeamViewer 6.

[image: screenshot of TemViewer configurations]

1. Download TeamViewer 6 https://download.teamviewer.com/download/version_6x/TeamViewer_Setup.exe
2. Install it.
3. Go to menu `extras\options\general` and select the Incoming LAN connection (Accept\accept only).

Comment: This works with version 12 of teamviewer too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Presentation Mode in TeamViewer 6. I tried it in new versions and it did not work. You can get old versions of TeamViewer from [OldVersion.com](http://www.oldversion.com/windows/teamviewer/), [OldApps.com](http://www.oldapps.com/teamviewer.php) or [FileHippo](http://www.filehippo.com/download_teamviewer/history/).

Answer (score 0):

As well as extras -> options -> general -> incoming -> accept LAN connections, you may need to select the remote host's Teamviewer ID (123 456 789) instead of its IP address (192.168.1.107).